# off canvas menu in container with bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, canvas

I'm trying to build an "off canvas menu" like that on www.bikepacking.com,
but I'm struggling with using this in a container.

I use Bootstrap with QuantumUI and *without* jQuery.

My approach is something like this:

```
<div class="container wrapper">

  <rw-navigation>

  </rw-navigation>

  <div class="brandbar">
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger"/>
    <label for="nav-trigger"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <header>

    </header>

    <div ui-view=""></div>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2015 {{'footer.copyright' | translate}}</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

With some styles like this:

```
div.container.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  .navigation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 256px;
    @include transition(left, 0.5s, ease);
    background: #111;
    color: white;
  }
  .brandbar{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left:0;
    @include transition(left, 0.5s, ease);
  }
  .content {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

The `.navigation` class is applied in the template of the `rwNavigation` directive with `replace: true`.

It doesn't work and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

OK,

Now I got some tima at work for that problem.

THX@ Sitepoint for this tutorial which gave me the right direction:

http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/

BUt I had to change form `position:fixed` to `position:absolute`, because `position:fixed` only refer to the window and `position:absolute` refer to prant `position:relative` element (or windows if there isnt a parent `postion:relative` element)

And here is a plnkr with the solution for a boxed off canvas menu

http://plnkr.co/edit/OdkXXkhGzKLd0qi2RZ4h?p=preview